# Javascript Not Running or Working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jsfiddle

I have a project that includes a login form with a password meter. I followed [a tutorial from cssdeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/yze3ymgf), then tried copy-pasting the code into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hkdL51p/) to see results. It works on the demo, but not on [my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hkdL51p/). The issue is the password meter not working. I have read through the JavaScript and can not see anything wrong with it.
Any suggestions would be nice. Why does the exact same code not work in the Fiddle?

```js
$(function(){
    var pass1 = $('#password1'),
        pass2 = $('#password2'),
        email = $('#email'),
        form = $('#main form'),
        arrow = $('#main .arrow');

    // Empty the fields on load
    $('#main .row input').val('');

    // Handle form submissions
    form.on('submit', function(e){
        // Is everything entered correctly?
        if ($('#main .row.success').length == $('#main .row').length) {
            // Yes!
            alert("Thank you for trying out this demo!");
            e.preventDefault();
            // Remove this to allow actual submission
        } else {
            // No. Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    // Validate the email field
    email.on('blur', function(){
        // Very simple validation
        if (!/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/.test(email.val())) {
            email.parent().addClass('error').removeClass('success');
        } else {
            email.parent().removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        }
    });

    // Use the complexify plugin on the first password field
    pass1.complexify({minimumChars: 6, strengthScaleFactor: 0.7},
        function(valid, complexity){
            if (valid) {
                pass2.removeAttr('disabled');
                pass1.parent().removeClass('error').addClass('success');
            } else {
                pass2.attr('disabled','true');
                pass1.parent().removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            }

            var calculated = (complexity / 100) * 268 - 134;
            var prop = 'rotate(' + (calculated) + 'deg)';
            // Rotate the arrow
            arrow.css({
                '-moz-transform': prop,
                '-webkit-transform': prop,
                '-o-transform': prop,
                '-ms-transform': prop,
                'transform': prop
            });
        }
    );

    // Validate the second password field
    pass2.on('keydown input', function(){
        // Make sure its value equals the first's
        if (pass2.val() == pass1.val()) {
            pass2.parent().removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        } else {
            pass2.parent().removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        }
    });
});
```

The [jquery.complexify](http://github.com/danpalmer/jquery.complexify.js) plugin is included as well.

Comment: The password meter works for me in the fiddle. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you included [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) properly in your page?

Comment: It seems to work for me in the Original Post, but not in my Project. Here is a Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/9hkdL51p/

Comment: At least in your JSFiddle the complexity assessing function is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't included jQuery library in your code.

this is from your fiddle
[image]

You need to include jQuery like this in the fiddle
[image]

This is a fiddle of your same code after adding jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/5n90vLgn/

in your page you need to include it ***before*** writing your js code or including an external js file, to include jquery from a CDN <sup>(*)</sup>, i.e

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

or include local copy of jQuery like:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js/"></script>
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> The above CDN is from jQuery website, there are other CDN of jquery though like [Google libraries](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js) or [CDNjs libraries](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/)

Comment: @HoneyBadgerYTB I'm not the person who answer, but in case you forget, accepting ( clicking the green tick on the left of this answer ) the answer will be helpful.